# Implementing RabbitMQ in Chrome Kiosk/Extension/Apps and Web Browsers

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

I'm developing internal applications that require push notifications but we cannot use outside services. I have started to work with RabbitMQ and have it working flawlessly inside of .NET Core. When trying to implement it the same thing with javascript I am not getting the same results.

I developed test clients in C#. I developed a client in javascript. I can make a successful connection but data is not arriving.

In C# I am using:

```
            string e = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a message (blank for test msg)");
            string message = Console.ReadLine();

            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "10.222.2.160" };
            factory.UserName = "Test";
            factory.Password = "TestPassword";
            factory.VirtualHost = "/";
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection("TestChannel"))
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {

                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: e,
                                     routingKey: "",
                                     basicProperties: null,
                                     body: body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
            }
```

In Javascript:

```
var wsbroker = "10.222.2.160";  // mqtt websocket enabled broker
        var wsport = 15675; // port for above
        var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport, "/ws/",
            "test");

        client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
            console.log("CONNECTION LOST - " + responseObject.errorMessage);
        };
        client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
            console.log("RECEIVE ON " + message.destinationName + " PAYLOAD " + message.payloadString);

        };

        var options = {
            userName: "Test",
            password: "TestPassword",
            timeout: 3,
            keepAliveInterval: 30,
            onSuccess: function () {
                console.log("CONNECTION SUCCESS");
                client.subscribe('test', { qos: 1 });
            },
            onFailure: function (message) {
                console.log("CONNECTION FAILURE - " + message.errorMessage);
            }
        };
        if (location.protocol == "https:") {
            options.useSSL = true;
        }
        console.log("CONNECT TO " + wsbroker + ":" + wsport);
        client.connect(options);
```

I need to be able to connect to rabbitmq from javascript (non-node, chrome kiosk application/chrome extension). However, I'm not sure I am "understanding" RabbitMQ. Pointing me in the right direction would help a girl out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're publishing without a routing key here:

```
            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: e,
                                 routingKey: "",
                                 basicProperties: null,
                                 body: body);
```

Ensure that the `test` queue exists, then change `routingKey` to `test` in your publisher, and use the exchange named `amq.direct`.

You should read the RabbitMQ introduction available here to get familiar with how exchanges, queues, routing keys and bindings interact:

https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-18-part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html

Comment: Hey Luke, thanks for the quick response! I read over the documentation and it definitely is what I've been looking for and clears a lot of questions up. Now, I can say I have this working flawlessly in C#. My issue appears to be when it comes to the Paho Javascript library. It seems to be fairly limited and only supports subscribing to topics. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I just noticed you're using MQTT. MQTT uses topics "behind the scenes". I suggest searching on "RabbitMQ MQTT AMQP integration" to see how people link the two up. The other alternative is to use a C# MQTT client library.